# Vulkan rendering of Minecraft-like world in C++

Tags: c++, textures, voxels, texture-atlas, vulkan

I decided on using 16x16x16 (4096 total) chunks of blocks.

Problem is with textures.
First idea was about **texture atlas** but it would require a lot of calculation and possible problems in dividing UV (1) by atlas size (power of 2).
Then I was thinking about using **array of textures** or **`sampler2darray`**.

I do not have fixed amount of textures and I reserved `uint16` (`65,535`) for block-only textures (those textures are not used anywhere else, even items have their own item-only textures).
All those textures are loaded before the world (based on loaded "mods").

I got so far that **array of textures** should be best solution because they support different resolutions (8x8, 16x16, 32x32, 64x64...) without duplicated pixels (which **`sampler2darray`** would require when even 1 texture has higher resolution because all textures would be re-scaled to fit it).

Problems I found with **array of textures** are:

- the length must also be defined in shader (which I would need to recompile at runtime)
- limited length (`256` to `2048` based on [vulkan.gpuinfo.org](https://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displaydevicelimit.php?name=maxImageArrayLayers) but even Minecraft has [`229` block types](https://www.minecraftinfo.com/idlist.htm), some with multiple textures)

Advantages are:

- possible ["greedy" mesh optimization](https://0fps.net/2012/06/30/meshing-in-a-minecraft-game/) reducing number of vertices utilizing `VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_REPEAT` (`GL_REPEAT` in OpenGL)

Which type of storage for textures is best in this case?

Or should I separate faces by textures, create [VkPipeline](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/VkPipeline.html) for each texture and render them one by one?

EDIT:
Each block has at least 1 texture (most time unique) but can be higher then 6 (different texture for each face) when 1 block is made of multiple cubes = non-solid.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd have problems with textures in a minecraft-line world. I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but you don't need to create a separate texture for each cube, if all cubes are "earth" cubes for example, they should share the same one. That means 1 texture for multiple cubes.

Comment: @TomTsagk Yes but Minecraft has 229 unique block types (I edited "blocks" to "block types"), with mods it can easily go to 1,000.
I want it to be capable of those (not limited to only few).

Comment: The general idea is that its better to combine textures together, especially if you try to mean constrains like power of 2 sizes. Several atlases would be a good idea to start with. I'm not sure what you mean by "it would require a lot of calculations and possible problems". Drawing an objects using an atlas as source shouldn't be any more resource intensive than objects that use a single texture as source.

Comment: @TomTsagk by the "require a lot of calculations" I mean translating "block texture id" to UV coordinates and possible problems with floating-point numbers.

Comment: I'm not familiar how minecraft works behind the scenes, by if you save all blocks as `.ply` or a similar format, you can save UV's there, and achieve the same result with not having to do any calculations at all,

Comment: I use custom format (currently only inside source code) where everything is AA-Box with defined rendered faces (flags).
But even if I was using external file, having different atlas layout (order of images) would require recalculating UV.

So I should use 4096x4096 texture atlas ([2D Image Limit](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displaydevicelimit.php?name=maxImageDimension2D) but only for 1 so it can be increased to 8192x8192 to multiply the amount by 4) and when it reaches maximum blocks (65,536 for 16x; 16,384 for 32x; 4,096 for 64x; 1,024 for 128x), just create another pipeline for those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[2D Image Limit](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displaydevicelimit.php?name=maxImageDimension2D) is 8192.
That means much more textures then using any type of array.

Using this for only 1 atlas means:

- `16x` ~ 262,144
- `32x` ~ 65,536
- `64x` ~ 16,384
- `128x` ~ 4,096
- `256x` ~ 1,024
- `1024x` ~ 256

`16x` means 16x16 pixels per texture, `32x` means 32x32 and so on.

Exceeding this limit would require creating more [VkImage](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/VkImage.html) -> [VkPipeline](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/VkPipeline.html) (and when rendering chunks, split it into more meshes).

Because of this, I may settle on keeping only 1 atlas.
`32x` textures means average of 2 textures per block (`32,767`, maximum of `int16_t` used for block IDs), `16x` ~ 8 textures per block, `64x` ~ 1 texture per 2 blocks.

This will also limit servers to use lower resolution or less block, further decreasing impact on performance.

Comment: servers wouldn't even use the texture, servers have no use for displaying client side graphics.

Comment: @opa The way I have it designed is having server-side mods which requires server to send all the textures to used (when he does not have it already stored, checked by hash).
So the server is telling the visuals and functionality.

This project is just multiple prototype tests - Vulkan, server-side-only mods and LUA.

Comment: Server need only send the texture data then, again, the server does not need to render anything. Lowering or increasing texture resolution would do nothing except increase or decrease bandwidth usage on startup for new players, it does not tax the server because the server shouldn't be doing anything with the textures except serving them.

Comment: @opa server is saying which textures and at which resolution should be used.
That means if server sends texture with 128x128 resolution (2^7) then it can only send 16,384 textures total because of limit on client's side (maximum atlas size, see the answer's text).

Server is not rendering it but need to be aware of this limit.

Comment: @AbitGray: No, it doesn't. It should send the available data; it's up to the *client* to decide how to render the available data. If it wants to reduce the resolution of some images, it can. If it has some hardware limitation, then the client should figure out how best to deal with it.

Comment: @NicolBolas The design idea is that server tells how they are rendered and provides all needed data (like textures, light sources...).
So client needs to receive full textures even when they would want to use lower resolution (higher mip-map) as default.
But because I am writing both client and server (and it is prototype), I will settle on 1 atlas (created on server and sent to client) to reduce need for switching (separating) between atlases (and vkPipeline).
The 8192 is minimum size supported under all Vulcan-compatible devices => minimum "maximum value".